# jQuery event triggered when clicking outside the list

Tags: jquery

I am trying to trigger a click event on every item in a nested list and return the text  of the clicked item. The return text part works fine but when I click outside the list, it still triggers the click event and returns the text of the list item in the corresponding line. Has anyone faced such an issue?

HTML:

```
 <div id="myDiv">
    <ul id = "u" class="nam">
      <li id="i1" class="nam">John</li>
      <li id="i2" class="nam">
          <ul id="uu">
             <li id="i3">F</li>
             <li id="i4">Fitzgerald</li>
          </ul>    
      </li>
      <li id="i5" class="nam">Kennedy</li>
     </ul>
   </div>
```

jQuery Code:

```
  $("#u").on("click","li",function(event){
   event.stopPropagation();
   alert($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: `<ul id = "u" class="nam">` probably should have no space around `=`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that without any width styling, your div and UL is taking the whole width of the page.

You can see that example here: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/W5v3d/)

If you give the div some with, the problem will be gone ( the container to click will be smaller )

```
width: 200px;
```

Answer (score 1):

Giving fixed width will solve that but another solution is wrapping `li` content with `span`. You can do this with jquery if you dont wanna do it in your html code then build your click event for `li span` selector.

```
$("li").not(":has(ul li)").wrapInner("<span></span>");

$("#u").on("click","li span",function(event){
  event.stopPropagation();
  alert($(this).text());
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gt5QR/)

Answer (score 0):

Just style your div ul li and your problem will be solved because the element you are using they are the block element which using the full page, so style your page or provide some fixed pixel it will work.